# NextGen CSS Not Working

Tags: css, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I added the NextGen Gallery plugin to my wordpress installation, but for some reason the CSS is not working. You can see this here: http://cbchaverhill.onedirectionconnection.com/?page_id=678

I checked to see if CSSfor Next was being included in the header and there doesn't seem to be any additional CSS being added to my header. So I went searching for the CSS in the plugin folders to add it manually to the header... but I couldn;t find any CSS.

If anyone could advise me on this issue, it would b greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I've added  and some CSS is included in the header, but the CSS thar isrequired to style the gallery is not being called.

Answer (score 1):

These plugins almost work with wordpress functions in header and footer.

did you called them ?

```
<?php wp_head() ?>
```

+

```
<?php wp_footer() ?>
```

put theme in your theme and test again. 
the css file should be display.

Comment: I've added <?php wp_head(); ?> to the header but the CSS still doesn't look like it should. It should look like this: http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/nextgen-gallery-demos/#gallery

Comment: if you are sure you activated the plugin, you can copy CSS code from that address and put in your header and change the site address , try this .

Comment: This was my issue.  None of the NextGen effects or styling were working in my custom theme.  Although the above English is quite hard to understand it was correct.  I was missing the <?php wp_footer() ?> in the footer and adding this in made everything magically appear.